# The continuum hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, logic

I was reading about the continuum hypothesis, and if i understood correctly, the hypothesis is

**true and false at the same time !**

Now that make me wonder what if with another set of axioms, some of our proven theorems could be proven wrong, for instance the four color theorem with another set of axioms would be false, is this possible.

The question : does every statement neither true nor false but it depend on the set of axioms ?!

Comment: Seemingly-trivial-but-actually-highly-nontrivial-question: what do you mean by "true"?

Comment: Comments welcome on how to improve https://www.patrickstevens.co.uk/independence-of-choice/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not accurate to say that CH (the continuum hypothesis) is true and false at the same time; rather, the usually accepted axioms of set theory (namely, [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)) are known to not be enough to settle the question: as long as they are consistent, they can neither prove nor disprove CH.

But this isn't as strange as it may sound at first. Let's consider another set of axioms - the [**group axioms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition). There are lots of interesting statements that these axioms neither prove nor disprove: for instance, commutativity ($x*y=y*x$ for all $x, y$). What this means is that there are some groups which are commutative (or "abelian"), and others which aren't. Similarly, the undecidability of CH in ZFC means that (assuming ZFC has any models in the first place) there are some models of ZFC in which CH holds, and some in which it fails.

In fact, it turns out that [any theory that can "do enough mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) is always going to have reasonable-sounding statements which it can neither prove nor disprove. For ZFC, it just happens to be the case that CH is one of these.

---

Now this makes sense if we treat ZFC as just another set of mathematical laws, which describe a certain class of objects. But what about the "real" universe of sets?

*That is: is the continuum hypothesis "actually true" or not?*

Well, if one believes in such a thing (opinions on this vary wildly), then the takeaway is: knowing that the ZFC axioms are "true" doesn't tell us whether CH is "true." CH is either true or false - not both at the same time - but the axioms of ZFC alone aren't enough to tell us which it is. If all we know about the "real" universe of sets is that it satisfies ZFC, then we don't have enough information to tell whether CH is true. In order to settle CH, we would need to identify **new axioms** of set theory - this has been [studied extensively by a number of set theorists](http://logic.harvard.edu/efi.php).

At the other extreme, we can posit that there is no universe of sets,the ZFC axioms are silly and don't describe anything that "actually exists," and so CH is simply a nonsense statement.

In between these two views are lots of other philosophies; see the lectures in my previous link.